# On post the string contains /r/n when enter is pressed

Tags: php, html

on my website when ever a user posts something and there is a enter button pressed in his post the post contains /r/n instead. This is the code i use

```
function validate_disclose($disclose)
{
    $stars = "****************************************************";
    $disclose = sanitize($disclose);
    $notallowed = array("fucked","stupid");
    foreach($notallowed as $bad){
        $disclose = str_ireplace($bad, substr($stars, 0, strlen($bad)), $disclose); // mixed case in i replace
    }
    return $disclose;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is just a formatting issue - if you use the following function:

```
return nl2br( $disclose );
```

then the instances of \r\n everything should be replaced by `<br />`. I am assuming that you want to display the output via HTML. If not then just use:

```
return preg_replace( "/\r\n|\r|\n/", 'WHATEVER YOU WANT TO REPLACE \r\n WITH ', $disclose );
```